# SVN post-update hook?

Tags: django, svn, apache, hook

Does it exist? Basically I'm developing a Django app on my local machine, when I've finished adding my feature and get it working locally, I want to `commit` it, and then `update` the production server.  Then I want to automatically restart apache. Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you want a CI server? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration

Answer (score 2):

The following probably wouldn't apply to you, as your more than likely in a linux environment, but on Windows, TortoiseSVN supports a post-update hook on the client side, if you go into `Settings` then `Hook Scripts`

Comment: Yeah.. that doesn't really help at all :\ I do have tortoise installed on my dev machine, but my production server is indeed linux.

Answer (score 1):

Why a post-commit hook not appropriate?

Comment: How would that work? I'm committing from my local dev machine... restarting apache at that point in time wouldn't do anything. Apache needs to be restarted *after* the production files have been updated.

Comment: So how are you updating the remote server then? You seemed to imply you wanted to commit, and have the server update and restart - in which case you could do both in the post-commit hook. If you are updating the remote server manually, then why couldn't whatever script you are using to do that be extended to restart the server as well?

Comment: I'm updating the remote server manually. I'm a naughty boy and all my commits aren't necessarily stable, so I don't want to update the server immediately. You're quite right that I could just use an update-and-restart script instead, Daniel. That'd work.